# Word count of ebooks (acsm)

Tags: adobe-digital-editions, acsm

Is there any way to extract a word count from `.acsm` (with DRM) eBooks? I can only view them in Adobe Digital Editions and this doesn't have a word count feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.acsm` files contain only Adobe Content Server download instructions, not the actual ebook. If you want to generate word counts, you'll have to download the actual epub, remove the DRM and use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download).

Comment: Thanks. Ignoring the DRM issue - say I want to only deal with freely-available, archived books - can Calibre yield a word count?

Comment: @lithic: Yes with the optional [Count Pages plugin](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=1547631). It also offers English readability statistics.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. And is there an way to derive word counts for content in the desktop version of Amazon Kindle?

Comment: No, but the Calibre Count Pages plugin supports Kindle files, too. :-)